# Call requires API level 11 (current min is 1)

Tags: android

I just removed the support library (I will support only one device, of API level 15) and my code runs fine after cleaning of the project. However, when I only touch the file in which I use `getFragmentManager()`, I get this Lint error.

Weird thing is that I have `minSdkVersion` in my manifest set to 15:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="15"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

I searched for this error, but all it says basically is to clean lint markers or clean the project. Which works, but only just one time.

**Update** it is even worse. If I don't clean, but just resave the file, the errors add up. I started with 6 errors, I have 24 now....

Comment: clean and build the project

Comment: @Raghunandan that works, but only once. If I save the file again, the error pops up again.

Comment: @Raghunandan Project->Properties->Android->Target is set to 4.3 (API 18)

Comment: does your project.properties contain something like "target=android-1" ??

Comment: Project/Android/Fix Project Properties

Comment: @bofredo no. It says `target=android-18`

Comment: It feels like Eclipse is screwing up the interpretation of your manifest. Have you restarted Eclipse since this problem began?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes I have. I just tried to Close and Re-open the project, then restart eclipse. Problem is still there.

Comment: I even removed the project and reinserted again into the workspace, no change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea what the exact cause was, but I got it fixed by re-creating the project from scratch, by checking out freshly out of SVN again. (I had to because I got a new laptop).

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same issue.
I clean and build the project multiple times, but getting this issue again and again.
I clean and build the project and then restarted the eclipse.
It is working fine for me now.

Answer (score 2):

That's interesting.
I also faced the same issue and wasted more than an hour on it.

Finally, The reason I found was, I opened two different projects in two different windows of Android Studio. And both projects gradle configuration were different.
When I closed another project window and ***restarted*** my android studio, Error has gone, and it was working perfectly. :)

Seems like it's an Android Studio bug, and sometimes the dissimilarities between two projects configuration in two different windows at the same time generate this error.

Comment: currently looking at 2 different versions of AS open and seeing the error so looks like it's still the issue

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this way

Select File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart.

Answer (score 0):

This happens the same to me, after I `Team -> Share Project` shared the project in elipse.

I added the `android-support-*.jar` library from `/libs` to the build path and this solved my problem.

Comment: The problem started when I removed the support library. And I want it removed, as I am only targeting one device.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this way

Add `minSdkVersion 21` in build.gradle file

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_9
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
    }
}
```